# Using PHP fWrite to save HTML data causes formatting issues

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter

I created a part of my CMS that allows admins to convert all the text on the page to textareas, so they can edit the content. All the content they change is inside a div, and I submit via jQuery / AJAX the div's content to the PHP controller that processes the data. However, jQuery grabs the HTML just perfectly and sends it to the PHP controller, but the PHP butchers some of the content (removing some tags, every so often).

For example, if I submit

```
<div class="cmsedit" style="background-color:#EEE">Hello</div>
```

it will save/write the file with this

```
div class="cmsedit">Hello</div> .
```

It removes the opening bracket to the div and the b. It doesnt do it all the time. If I don't include a style tag, it generally leave the code just fine.

Here is the code I'm using on the javascript page.

```
$('.save_page').click(function(){
    updated_content = $('.content_to_be_edited').html();
    edit_page = $('#edit_page_name').val();
    $.post("<?=site_url('admin/update_page_data') ?>", { content:updated_content,page_name:edit_page });    
});
```

Here is the PHP Controller Page

```
    $page_content = $this->input->post('content');
    $page_name = $this->input->post('page_name');       
    $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/application/views/".$page_name.".php";

    // SAVE NEW FILE
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Can't open file");
    $filedata = htmlspecialchars_decode($page_content);
    fwrite($file, $filedata);
    fclose($file);
```

Anyone have any ideas why the tags are getting all screwed up when the PHP processes the data? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you done a echo on the $page_content to make sure you're receiving it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have the codeigniter XSS filter active which will destroy your data.

You can disable it and then it should work.

Comment: Good call. Didn't think of that. Thanks.